# Aip8563 can’t read out data byte

Tags: c, embedded

I am using aip8536 rtc timer chip!
When I write data to register like scond register through the I2C bus,the ack is 0! When I reading data byte from the specific register which I have written data byte into it successfully, the ack  is 0, but the  data byte is 0x00!
Why? I have checked the soft I2C buss gpio configuration,because I have used this code to read and write AT24C64. The AT24C64 and AIP8564 is loaded on the same I2C buss!I have added proper delay time between writing and reading register!However I still got the data byte 0x00.

I want to figure out what should I do to resolve this problem!

Comment: Please tell what data byte value you are expecting.   Also please share the code you are using in this effort. Thanks and welcome to Stackoverflow.

Comment: OK，thanks! I will share my code!

Comment: Delay_ms(500);
 MyI2C_Start();
 MyI2C_SendByte(0xA2);
 temp13 = MyI2C_ReceiveAck();
 MyI2C_SendByte(0x02); //秒寄存器
 temp14 = MyI2C_ReceiveAck();
 MyI2C_SendByte(0x59);
 temp15 = MyI2C_ReceiveAck();
 MyI2C_Stop();

Comment: Delay_ms(500);
 MyI2C_Start();
 MyI2C_SendByte(0xA2);
 temp16=MyI2C_ReceiveAck();
 MyI2C_SendByte(0x02);
 temp17=MyI2C_ReceiveAck();
 MyI2C_Start();
 MyI2C_SendByte(0xA3);
 temp18=MyI2C_ReceiveAck();
 temp_data = MyI2C_ReceiveByte();
 MyI2C_SendAck(1);
 MyI2C_Stop();

Comment: I am expecting the data byte what I have written to second register is 0x59.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and read "[ask]". Then come back and [edit] your question to add new information. As you found you are not supposed to use comments for this, therefore please delete the comments after expanding your question. Oh, and while you're at it, please translate any non-English parts.

Comment: @Klen Yan -- hi!   I'm so sorry, I meant to say "please share your code by editing your question."    Code placed in the comments doesn't work well.  Please also try to provide enough of the code so it will compile for us.  We often like to help by compiling the code given in a question to see if the error is reproduced.  Thanks